# Swift array.map conver NSNumber to UInt

Tags: swift, swift2

```
let myArray = Array(arrayLiteral: userIDs)
let newArray = myArray.map{$0 as! UInt}
```

What does the following error mean?

> Cast from 'Set?' to unrelated type 'UInt' always fails

I want to convert an array created from `NSSet` to array with `UInt` instead of numbers.

Comment: Did you try using `unsignedIntegerValue` method instead of casting? `let newArray = myArray.map{$0!.unsignedIntegerValue}`

Comment: What is `userIDs`? – I don't know any case where you really need to call an `xxxLiteral:` constructor explicitly, so I *assume* that you did that to work around another problem.

Comment: @MartinR it's a set of nsnumbers

Comment: ok let me add few comments here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `userIDs` is `Set<NSNumber>` then doing `Array(arrayLiteral: userIDs)` does not create an array from the set contents, it creates an array containing the set itself.

Remove the `arrayLiteral` init:

```
let num1 = NSNumber(integer: 33)
let num2 = NSNumber(integer: 42)
let num3 = NSNumber(integer: 33)
let nums = [num1, num2, num3] // [33, 42, 33]
let userIDs = Set(nums) // {33, 42}
let myArray = Array(userIDs) // [33, 42]
```

Then you can map to whatever you want:

```
let newArray = myArray.map{ UInt($0) }
```

**UPDATE after your comment**

If you have a Foundation's NSSet instead of a Swift's Set, you can do this:

```
let userIDs = NSSet(array: nums)
let myArray = userIDs.map { $0 as! NSNumber }
let newArray = myArray.map { UInt($0) }
```

We have to downcast the content of NSSet to NSNumber since NSSet doesn't retain the element's type.

Comment: hm got it, but it does not allow me use let myArray = Array(userIDs), Xcode says maybe I want to add arrayLiteral. Actually I don't create Set as you, I get it from pods objective c files which NSSet, I am not sure if there is a differences.

Comment: ha, seems we have `Cast from 'Set<NSNumber>' to unrelated type 'NSNumber' always fails`on line `let myArray = userIDs.map { $0 as! NSNumber }`

Comment: It looks like your variable is actually *containing* at least one 'Set<NSNumber>'. In my example the variable *was* the Set. You should inspect your objects with the debugger (or print the contents) to be sure what they are. I'll help if needed but you first need to be sure what type of object you have otherwise I'm blind.

Comment: thanks for help! ok got it, when I print it: ```Optional<Set<NSNumber>>
  ▿ Some : 15 elements
    - [0] : 8241866```

Comment: I try to print first item and get this `[0] = <could not resolve type>`

Comment: seems like `unwrappedUserIDs.map{$0.unsignedLongValue}`works for me, I unwrapped it with `guard let unwrappedUserIDs = userIDs else {`

Answer (score 0):

if `userIds` is a `NSSet`, then `myArray` has one element in it of type `NSSet`.  You can map over userIDs though.

```
let userIDs: NSSet = NSSet(array: [ NSNumber(int:1), NSNumber(int:2), NSNumber(int:3) ] )

let myArray = Array(arrayLiteral: userIDs )
print( myArray.count) // returns 1
print( myArray[0].dynamicType)

let  newArray = userIDs.map { x -> UInt in
    print(x.dynamicType)
    return x as! UInt
}

for x in newArray {
    print( x.dynamicType )
}
```

This yields in playground:

```
1
__NSSetI
__NSCFNumber
__NSCFNumber
__NSCFNumber
UInt
UInt
Uint
```